# Gleam unexpected struct

Tags: compiler-errors, gleam

I'm 100% new to Gleam and tried a simple struct example I found.

```
// src/first.gleam

pub struct Cat {
  name: String
  is_cute: Bool
}

pub fn main() {
  Cat(name: "Nubi", is_cute: True)
}
```

However, I get a compile error:

```
% gleam run
error: Syntax error
  ┌─ C:\Users\Sven\programming\Gleam\first\src\first.gleam:3:1
  │
3 │ pub struct Cat {
  │ ^^^ I was not expecting this

Expected one of:
An import, const, type, if block, or function.
```

What is the solution to this?

Version output:
`% gleam --version gleam 1.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the compiler gives a hint: `Expected one of: An import, const, type, if block, or function.`.

```
pub type Cat {
  Cat(name: String, is_cute: Bool)
}
```

Comment: The example I copied uses Gleam 0.5, so is the struct keyword deprecated?